# Flex Object Identification Using Chrome in Test Complete

Tags: testcomplete

I am Automation Flex based Application using Test Complete 
I have completed script creation for IE Browser. Not have to work with Firefox , google chrome and Safari Browser.

In Chrome I have used SmartBear Extension however the flex object are not getting displayed in object browser. can anyone help me on that.

Answer (score 0):

Google Chrome has its own Flash player and this requires specific settings. You can find information on how to set up Flex testing for Google Chrome in the **For Google Chrome users** section of the [Configuring Adobe Flash Player](http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/62799/) help topic.

Comment: I have done that but still not able to get flex object in object browser

Comment: In this case you should contact the vendor Support team (http://support.smartbear.com/message/?prod=TestComplete) so they can investigate the issue specifically in your case.